# Code blocks in Developer CV have trailing newlines

Tags: bug

In my developer CV, in the Top Answer section, all of the answers I picked to display that include blocks of code have an empty line at the bottom.

I assume this isn't intentional, but maybe I'm wrong. Here's what I mean.

[image]

Very minor issue, but it might as well be consistent with the main site.